# How to easily group and drive signals in VHDL testbench

Tags: vhdl

Let's say I have 3 control signals A, B and C.

In the testbench is there a function in VHDL to group this and iterate all cases quickly (to enable them to be iterated with a for loop for example) rather than write out 8 cases.

Psuedo code example:

```
for i in range 0 to 7
 grouped_signals <=std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i,3)
```

Comment: You can use the code, which you showed as example, and then in `port map` use this signal for different inputs as `A => grouped_signals(0), B => grouped_signals(1), C => grouped_signals(2)`.

Comment: (A, B, C) <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i,3); where the left hand side target of the assignment is an aggregate. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.3.3 Array aggregates, 10.5 Signal assignment statement, 10.5.2 Simple signal assignments, 10.5.2.1 (and for a variable assignment 10.6 Variable assignment statement, ...). The type of (A, B, C) is the type of right hand side expression and there is a matching element of the target for every element of the right hand side expression. This uses positional association.

Comment: This works, the problem was primarily a type mismatch and locality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be a signal assignment where the target is an aggregate:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity agg_assign is
end entity;

architecture foo of agg_assign is
    signal A, B, C: std_logic;
begin
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        for i in 0 to 7 loop
            (A, B, C) <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i, 3));
            wait for 10 ns;
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

And that produces:

[image: agg_assign.png]