# VHDL Vivado: Can I make a variable std_logic_vector from separate std_logic inputs in the test bench?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I'm trying to build an ALU and I want to test it with a loop, the problem is that I have separate `std_logic` inputs and for a loop I need a vector of the inputs.
I tried making a vector of the inputs with variable and I got this error: `[XSIM 43-3294] Signal EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION received.`

I don't know what this error means, here is my test bench:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


entity TB_ALU is
--  Port ( );
end TB_ALU;

architecture Behavioral of TB_ALU is
component ALU is
    Port ( INVA, A, ENA, B, ENB, cin, f1, f0: in STD_LOGIC;
           cout : buffer STD_LOGIC;
           output : out STD_LOGIC);
end component;

signal INVA, A, ENA, B, ENB, cin, output, cout, f1, f0 : STD_LOGIC;
begin
U2: ALU port map (INVA=>INVA, A=>A, ENA=>ENA, B=>B, ENB=>ENB, cin=>cin, f1=>f1, f0=>f0, output=>output, cout=>cout);

process
variable input : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0):=(f1, f0, ena, enb, inva, cin);
begin
wait for 10ns;
a<='1'; b<='1';

lp: for i in 0 to 63 loop  
    input := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i,6));
    WAIT FOR 10ns;
    end loop lp;
wait;
end process;


end Behavioral;
```

Comment: You try to connect the signals to the variable  input by "variable input : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0):=(f1, f0, ena, enb, inva, cin);". But with this line you only initialize the variable input. You have to declare a signal input, assign values to it in your process and then connect input to the alu by for example "cin <= input(0);".  I don't know the reason for the XSIM message, but perhaps the missing blanks in your time values are the reason: Instead of "10ns" you must use "10 ns".

Comment: I looked at 5 examples of the error, all caused by XSIM no recognizing valid syntax. The initial value expression in the declaration of variable input is not useful (the signals are all 'U' during elaboration) and probably caused the issue. In a standard compliant tool an aggregate signal assignment `(f1, f0, ena, enb, inva, cin) <=  input;` could be used before the wait statement in the loop. For example IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.3 "At least one separator is required between an identifier or an abstract literal and an adjacent identifier or abstract literal", (10 ns, a portability issue).

Comment: The method in Renaud's answer using the loop parameter in a conversion first to type unsigned then to std_logic_vector is also demonstrated in the answer to [How to easily group and drive signals in VHDL testbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43629450/how-to-easily-group-and-drive-signals-in-vhdl-testbench/43631161#43631161) which isn't a duplicate,the question lacking a [mcve] and a specific error. Finding it here  would require search terms defined in the standards as well (*[vhdl] aggregate signal assignment*). Readers are curious. Did you fix your problem, if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be spaces between `10` and `ns` (2 occurrences). But your code, that modifies a variable in a loop without any visible side effect, does not really make sense. If your goal is to generate all 64 combinations of your 6 signals with a `10 ns` pause between them try:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity tb_alu is
end entity tb_alu;

architecture behavioral of tb_alu is
  component alu is
    port(inva, a, ena, b, enb, cin, f1, f0: in std_ulogic;
         cout: buffer std_ulogic;
         output: out std_ulogic);
  end component;

  signal inva, a, ena, b, enb, cin, output, cout, f1, f0: std_ulogic;
begin

  u2: alu
  port map(inva => inva, a => a, ena => ena, b => b, enb => enb, cin => cin, f1 => f1, f0 => f0, output => output, cout => cout);

  process
  begin
    wait for 10 ns;
    a<='1';
    b<='1';
    lp: for i in 0 to 63 loop  
      (f1, f0, ena, enb, inva, cin) <= std_ulogic_vector(to_unsigned(i,6));
      wait for 10 ns;
    end loop lp;
    wait;
  end process;

end behavioral;
```

Simple example of left hand side aggregate of signal.

Note the replacement of all `std_logic` with `std_ulogic` (as long as you don't know the difference always use `std_ulogic`, never `std_logic`).